# Swapping with Paging and Swappiness (Linux)

Tags: linux, memory, operating-systems, swap

In Abraham Silberschatz's Book, Greg Gagne, Peter B. Galvin - Operating System Concepts (2018) says:

> Standard swapping was used in traditional UNIX systems, but it is
> generally no longer used in contemporary operating systems, because
> the amount of time required to move entire processes between memory
> and the backing store is prohibitive [...].
>
> Most systems, including
> Linux and Windows, now use a variation of swapping in which pages of a
> process—rather than an entire process—can be swapped. This strategy
> still allows physical memory to be oversubscribed, but does not incur
> the cost of swapping entire processes, as presumably only a small
> number of pages will be involved in swapping.

Is the parameter Swappiness actually a pagination type?

Comment: no, Swappiness allows you to configure the degree to which certain kinds of memory pages (file pages, which are easily reproducible) are swapped vs dropped when the decision is made to offload the page from main memory. Swappiness is also used to control how aggressively anonymous pages (which can't be recreated) are move to paging.  The algorithms behind virtual memory management are complex, but if you want to dig into it, check this out: https://www.howtogeek.com/449691/what-is-swapiness-on-linux-and-how-to-change-it/ . its an interesting read.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for the reading material! After reading this excerpt from the book I was very confused if some commands that involve swap in linux were in fact the standard swap or "swapping with paging"

Comment: no, the kernel doesn't work that way anymore (pages are swapped, not whole processes), so any commands related to it will either have been removed, or don't work. I believe there are also different kinds of swaping available between different kernel builds, based on modules and configuration.